# Display .jpg and .txt file value in modal pop up not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a code here which checks if a .txt and .jpg file exist in the server directory (im using cpanel) after an image click. and then it displays the value of the .txt file in alert box (*works well*) it should also display the image in the same box. but its returning the img source instead.

what i exactly want is:

1. display both files (the .txt value and the image) in a modal pop up
2. the .jpg on the left side of the pop up
3. the .txt value on the right side

the .txt file value is somthing like:

Title
Subtitle

paragraph here...

here's my code:
view.php

```
            <html>
                <head>
                    <title>Simple AJAX Example</title>
                    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <div class="Thumb popup_element shadow clearfix" id="u2413"><!-- group -->
                      <img class="grpelem" id="u2471" alt="This Week's Events" src="images/blank.gif" onclick="readexisting()"/><!-- state-based BG images -->
                    </div>

                    <script>
                        function readexisting() {
                             jQuery.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: 'controller.php',
                                data: {action: 'readexisting', arguments: 'your data'}, 
                                success:function(data) {
                                                     data = data.split("~:~");
                                                     alert(data[0]); // message

                                }
                            });
                        }
                    </script>
                </body>
            </html>
```

controller.php

```
            <?php
                include_once("model.php");

                $obj = new Model();

                switch($_POST["action"]){ 
                    case 'readexisting': 
                        $obj->readexisting();
                    break;      
                } 
            ?>
```

model.php

```
            <?php
            class Model {

               public function readexisting() {
                   if (file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/Project/events/folder-01/event-01.txt") && file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/Project/events/folder-01/event-01.jpg")) {  
                        $myPic = ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/Project/events/folder-01/event-01.jpg");
                        echo '<img src="'.$myPic.'" /><br />';

                        $myFile = ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/Project/events/folder-01/event-01.txt");
                        $fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
                        $theData = fread($fh, filesize($myFile));
                        fclose($fh);
                        echo $theData ; 

                   } else {
                        echo "The file $myFile does not exist";
                   }
               }

            }
            ?>
```

Hope you can help me with this. please feel free to edit my code. Your help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
$myPic = ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/Project/events/folder-01/event-01.jpg");
echo '<img src="'.$myPic.'" /><br />';
```

You are using a server path as a URL

Probably it should be

```
$myPic = "/Project/events/folder-01/event-01.jpg";
```

Comment: hi it's still displaying the path in the alert box. can you give me some more suggestions? how about how am i going to display it in a modal pop up instead of an alert box? thanks a lot! :)

Comment: thanks! it looks great! but i think it's a little bit complicated. i want something i can easily incorporate with my code. :)

Comment: it's really not that hard, in your `success()` callback you use it like this $.fancybox(
  your_html_string,
  {
          //options
  }
 );